# Codeigniter The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have developed a Attendance management system, i want to generate report by running following query, it will be a large number of rows, i am on shared host and getting below error :

**Query:**

```
SELECT 
 `attendance`.*, `users`.`id` AS user_id, 
CONCAT_WS(" ", `user_profiles`.`fname`, `user_profiles`.`lname` ) AS name,
`user_department`.`did`, `user_department`.`dep_name` FROM (`attendance`) 
    LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.`username` = `attendance`.`emp_code` 
    LEFT JOIN  `user_profiles` ON `user_profiles`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
    LEFT JOIN `in_department` ON `in_department`.`user_id` = `user_profiles`.`user_id`
    LEFT JOIN `user_department` ON `in_department`.`dep_id` = `user_department`.`did` 
WHERE `banned` = '0' 
   AND `for_date` >= '2012-05-28' 
   AND `for_date` <= '2012-06-28' 
ORDER BY `emp_code` asc, `for_date` asc
```

**Error:**

The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET    SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay

How I can run this query using active record in codeigniter 
SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1

Please help, do i need to index my table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply issue a query containing the `SET` command:

```
$this->db->query('SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1');
```

Comment: Thanks man, it works. I have only seven days data in system right now, i will check it again in month last.

Comment: i write this before query or after query?
please give an example